# How do I display disk usage for the storage volume on a google cloud dataflow streaming worker instance?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

How do I display disk usage for the storage volume on a streaming worker instance?

I logged in via ssh, and found the data disk in lsblk as `sdb`

```
$ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0    20G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0    20G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0   100G  0 disk
```

It does not appear in `mount` or `df` output. How do I found out how much space is being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data disks are mounted in a docker container, not directly to the VM.  You can see the list of running containers with

```
sudo docker ps
```

Find the windmill container, and connect to it with

```
sudo docker exec -it <container_id> bash
```

Then you can use standard unix tools to look at disk usage

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the disk is mounted in the 'windmill' container.